# Terminology for all derivatives non-negative

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functions, derivatives

I have a real-valued function $g(t)=e^{f(t)}$ where $t$ is either real or complex and lies in an open interval around $t=0$. I want to prove $g(t)$ is infinitely differentiable, and furthermore that all of the derivatives at $t=0$ are non-negative. For example, this condition is satisfied for the trivial function $f(t)=t$. Is there a technical term for this non-negativity condition? And are there any common techniques for this kind of proof?

Comment: I just realized the part about proving infinitely differentiable was addressed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159267/suppose-f-has-derivatives-of-all-orders-prove-that-fx-expfx-also-has . I'm still interested in proving the derivatives are non-negative.

Comment: Depending on what $f$ is, the derivatives may be negative. For instance, if $f(t) = -t$, then $g'(t) = -e^{-t} < 0$. I also don't understand what is meant by "$t$ is either real or complex" because you say $t$ lies in an open interval around $t = 0$. If $t$ is complex, do we take "interval" to mean "open ball"?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Ideally I want to assume t is real. But if necessary I can let it be complex, in which case yes I mean open ball around $t=0$. And I'm not trying to prove this for general function $f$ but rather I have a specific one in mind, something like $f(t)=b(t+c)^a$ where b,c are positive (real) constants and $1<a<2$. Not expecting folks to prove it for me, just trying to understand the terminology/ concepts around non-negative derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f: f^{(l)}\geq 0$ is called *absolutely monotone*, or  *totally monotone*; see

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolutely_monotonic_function

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $g(t)$ can always be computed with the chain rule, so long as $f(t)$ is differentiable. If the function $f(t)$ has the form $f(t) = b(t+c)^a$ where $b,c$ are real constants and $1 < a < 2$, then the derivative of $g(t)$ becomes
$$
g'(t) = f'(t)e^{f(t)} = ab(t+c)^{a-1}e^{f(t)}.
$$
As long as $t + c > 0$, so we don't need to make sense of possibly taking the $(a-1)$th root of a negative number, for instance, then the derivative $g'(t)$ is positive. When a function's derivative is positive everywhere, that function is an *increasing* function in the sense that whenever $t_1 < t_2$, then $f(t_1) < f(t_2)$. Moreover, $g(t)$ is infinitely differentiable because it is the composition of two infinitely differentiable functions, one of them being $t\mapsto e^t$ and the other $t\mapsto f(t)$. You could prove this using the chain rule and induction, for instance.

Comment: OK thanks for this detailed answer, but my main question is whether *all* of the derivatives of $g(t)$ are non-negative, not just the first one. The third derivative of $f$ is actually negative for the example function. Is there a mathematical term for the property that a function has all non-negative derivatives? Something like "super monotone"?

Comment: @WillTownes: There isn't any term that I am aware of for such functions, and it seems that you may have answered your own question about the sign of the higher derivatives.