# Questions about $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{X^{k}}{k!}$ with $X \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^{m}},\mathbb{R^m})$

Tags: analysis

For all $X \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R^m)$,

**1º**: the serie $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{X^{k}}{k!}$ is absolutely convergent.

Can i use the ratio test? (edit: no make sense.)

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\frac{\frac{X^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{X^{k}}{k!}}\right| =  \lim_{k \to \infty} \left| \frac{X}{k+1}\space\right| = 0 < 1$$ this is wrong.

*How can I use Cauchy Criterion to prove that?*

---

**2º**: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{X^{k}}{k!} = e^{X}$.

*How can I calculate that using MacLaurin series expansion?*

I know:
$$X(0) = 0, \space X^{(1)}(v) = \mathrm{const.}, \space X^{(n)}(v) = 0, \space \forall n>1$$

I tried to use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1159538/420023, but not success.

(edit: the definition of exponential of an operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)

---

Next **3º** and **4º** steps I dont have any idea how to proceed.

**3º**: $e^{X}.e^{Y} = e^{X+Y}$, since $XY = YX$.

I tried to use Cauchy product of power series, but i'm confused.

---

**4º**: For all $X \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R^m)$, $e^{X}$ is invertible with $(e^{X})^{-1} = e^{-X}$.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.  For instance, in 1º, you write $\left|\dfrac{\frac{X^{(k+1)}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{X^{k}}{k!}}\right|$.  What does that even mean to divide by $X^k$?  Then in 2º, you are asking about $e^X$, but how else do you define $e^X$ if not by the Maclaurin series?  Then in 3º, did you mean $e^X \cdot e^Y = e^{X+Y}$ if $XY=YX$?

Comment: N.B. 4° follows directly from 3°, since $X$ and $-X$ always commute.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to guess what your actual problem is, it would be

1. $\displaystyle\left\|\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{X^k}{k!}\right\| \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{\|X\|^k}{k!},$ so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{X^k}{k!}\right\| = 0$ and $\|e^X\| \leq e^{\|X\|}$.
2. By definition.
3. Assuming $XY=YX,$ so we can use the binomial theorem: $$\begin{align*}e^Xe^Y &= \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{X^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{Y^k}{k!}\right) \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^k\frac{X^nY^{k-n}}{n!(k-n)!} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{k}{n}X^nY^{k-n} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(X+Y)^k \\ &= e^{X+Y}\end{align*}$$
4. Since $X(-X) = -X^2 = (-X)X,$ we can apply the result of (3) to see $$e^X e^{-X} = e^{X+(-X)} = e^0 = I$$

Comment: I'm lacking some details on (1) and (2), but hopefully you can gather the main points.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {X^{k+1}} {X^{k}}$ makes no sense. You cannot divide one operator by another. Absolute convergence of $\sum \frac {X^{k}} {k!}$ is defined as convergence of the series of positive terms $\sum \frac {\|X^{k}\|} {k!}$. This series is dominated by $\sum \frac {\|X\|^{k}} {k!}$ which is clearly convergent.

2) is the definition of $e^{X}$.

3) is proves exactly the way you prove it when $X$ is real number.

4) follows from the fact that $e^{X}e^{-X}=e^{-X}e^{X}=e^{0}=I$.